# How to convert vector into JSON?

Tags: json, rust, vector, serialization

I want to use Rust to write a static website but I have a very basic problem to serve data for it. The code is roughly as follows:

```rust
pub struct Post {
    title: String,
    created: String,
    link: String,
    description: String,
    content: String,
    author: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut posts:Vec<Post> = Vec::new();
    let post = Post {
        title: "the title".to_string(),
        created: "2021/06/24".to_string(),
        link: "/2021/06/24/post".to_string(),
        description: "description".to_string(),
        content: "content".to_string(),
        author: "jack".to_string(),
    };
    posts.push(post);
}
```

How can I convert posts into JSON like:

```json
[{
    "title": "the title",
    "created": "2021/06/24",
    "link": "/2021/06/24/post",
    "description": "description",
    "content": "content",
    "author": "jack",
}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest solution is to use [serde](https://serde.rs/)'s derive abilities to have the JSON structure derived from your Rust struct:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Post {
    title: String,
    created: String,
    link: String,
    description: String,
    content: String,
    author: String,
}
```

Standard collections automatically implement `Serialize` when their content does.

You can thus build your json string with

```rust
let mut posts:Vec<Post> = Vec::new();
let post = Post {
    title: "the title".to_string(),
    created: "2021/06/24".to_string(),
    link: "/2021/06/24/post".to_string(),
    description: "description".to_string(),
    content: "content".to_string(),
    author: "jack".to_string(),
};
posts.push(post);
let json = serde_json::to_string(&posts)?;
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f17b3c42f8479ccecb355d9ff7ff2ee)